# Chinese characters rendered as squares in snap

Tags: snap

I am trying to build a snap but Chinese characters are rendered as squares. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image: chinese characters rendered as squares]

Here is my `snapcraft.yaml`:

```
name: cloudmusic
version: 1.4.3+snap2
summary: Cloud Music
description:
    Search, listen and download your favorite music
apps:
  cloudmusic:
    command: cloudmusic
    plugs: [unity7,opengl,home,network,network-bind,pulseaudio]

parts:
  cloudmusic:
    plugin: qmake
    qt-version: qt5
    options: [PREFIX=/usr]
    project-files: [CloudMusic.pro]
    source: src/
    build-packages:
      - build-essential
      - gettext
      - intltool
      - suru-icon-theme
      - qml-module-qt-labs-settings
      - qml-module-qtquick-localstorage
      - qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects
      - qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-download-manager0.1
      - qtdeclarative5-qtmultimedia-plugin
      - qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1
      - qt5-default
      - qtbase5-dev
      - qtdeclarative5-dev
      - qtdeclarative5-dev-tools
      - qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin
      - xvfb
    stage-packages:
      - ubuntu-sdk-libs
      - qtubuntu-desktop
      - qml-module-qtsysteminfo
      - fonts-freefont-ttf
    snap:
      - -usr/share/doc
      - -usr/include
  environment:
    plugin: copy
    files:
      cloudmusic.wrapper: bin/cloudmusic
      snappy-qt5.conf: etc/xdg/qtchooser/snappy-qt5.conf
```

Pastebin for the `snapcraft.yaml` above can be found at http://paste.ubuntu.com/19511184/.

Comment: I hope you get an answer here, but it might be a good idea to also file an official bug report. Snaps are new technology and it's quite possible this is an issue that needs to be addressed by the developers

Comment: Which package in Ubuntu usually provides Chinese fonts? Maybe it helps to add it to `stage-packages`?

Comment: `fonts-noto-cjk` maybe? (I'm just guessing.)

Comment: Do you have a link to your `snapcraft.yaml` file maybe?

Comment: i added the link to my snapcraft.yaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install fonts-wqy-zenhei`

This provides the required Chinese fonts.

Or you can download from [here](http://cooltext.com/Fonts-Unicode-Chinese)

And install from the GUI based font installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: Best comment, thanks for the link.