# Chinese Font in Firefox 98.0 (Snap version)

Tags: firefox, fonts, chinese

Firefox 98.0 (Snap version) does **not** support Chinese characters. For reference, https://hk.yahoo.com/ is render as

[image]

This should be fixable by changing the default font in "Preferences". Unfortunately, no font that support Chinese characters is listed in `Settings` > `Language and Appearance` > `Font and Colours` > `Default Font`:

[image]

I believe the source of the problem is Snap not be able to access the fonts available in the system. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is odd. Using the link that you've provided, I'm able to see what appears to be Chinese text with the Snap version of Firefox 98.0.1:

[image: Firefox Snap]

I've looked at my language settings and, while I do have the fonts for English and Japanese, I do not have any for Chinese. The page does load properly, though.

Digging deeper, if you click on the "Advanced" button in the "Language and Appearance" section of the Firefox settings, you'll see the ability to specify specific fonts for different character sets:

[image: Latin Fonts]

Changing the "Fonts for" option to "Simplified Chinese" or "Traditional Chinese (Hong Kong)" may show the same settings as is set for Latin. However, you may see other options that work better for you.

Alternatively, you could uninstall the Firefox snap from your system, then re-install. There is no `--reinstall` option like with `apt`, unfortunately.

---

**Edit:**

Another option comes from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/818102/1222991) where the `fonts-wqy-zenhei` font package was installed:

```
sudo apt install fonts-wqy-zenhei
```

This may resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Months ago, when I did `apt install firefox` it installed the snap version. When I run `apt install firefox` it installed the native version (I also installed firefox-locale-zh-hans and firefox-locale-zh-hant). Things are working as expected now in both native Firefox and snap one.